# How to make a button on bottomnavigation inactive depending on the value of the variable?

Tags: android

I have a bottomnavigation in the application that has buttons, so it turns out that this view element is initialized in the onCreate () function and the buttons that on this widget should depend on the server response. If the server response is true then the button is active, and if false, it is inactive. Here is the code for my view element:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_back:
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MessageShow.this, SecondScreen.class);
                        switch (type) {
                            case 0:
                                intent1.putExtra("id", 0);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                intent1.putExtra("id", 1);
                                break;
                        }

                        startActivity(intent1);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.action_delete:
                        return true;
                    case R.id.action_responce:
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MessageShow.this, WriteResponceMess.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

and here's the code for my request to the server:

```
if (response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String body = stripHtml(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getBody());
                    tvPerson.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getName());
                    tvTheme.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getSubject());
                    tvBody.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(body));
                    tvDate.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getDate());

                    String reply = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getCanReply();
                    if (reply.equals("true"))
                    {

                    }


                } else {
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("access_token_expired")) {
                            updateToken();
                        } else if (errorBody.string().contains("invalid_token")) {
                            logOut();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

and I need something that the availability of buttons depends on the response of the server. Here, for example, I got from the server that you can delete my message, and the button should become active and accessible for clicking. I will be very grateful for any help and useful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for disable menu item

> bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.action_delete).setEnabled(false);

for enable menu item

> bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.action_delete).setEnabled(true);

Comment: but how I can use your sulution at my onResponce method? as I understood it can be used only at onCreate?

Comment: Make bottomNavigationView as global variable then initialize in onCreate method and use in onResponse method as above

Comment: I honestly can not understand you correctly)) if you do not complicate please specify your answer

Comment: Above oncreate method write BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView; then in oncreate method  bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation); then in onresponse bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.action_delete).setEnabled(false);